# Track when the user received first bytes of the video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

There is a web page which has HTML5 video in it. When the user clicked start or when he navigates through the timeline, the video starts (either from start or from the position he selected). But it does not always happens instantly. I wanted to find how much time did it took from the user click event and the time the user received first bytes of the video.

Getting time of userclick is not a problem, but while looking through HTML5 video API [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-video-element) and I was not able to find any event which is close to what I am looking for.

Is it possible to tack such event?

Comment: You mean this event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/loadeddata ?

Comment: Wow, thank you I am not sure that this will work for navigating through the video but this is surely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The event(s) you listen for after you receive the click (or "play" or "seeking") event depends on the state of the video before the time of the click.

If you have a fresh, unplayed video element with the [preload](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/video_preload_attribute/) attribute set to "none", then the first data you're going to receive from the network is the metadata. so you can listen for the "loadedmetadata" event.

If preload is set to "metadata", you **might** have already loaded metadata, depending on the browser and platform. (e.g., Safari on iPad will not load metadata or anything else until the first user interaction.) In that case, you want to listen for either "loadedmetadata" or "progress". It couldn't hurt to listen for "loadeddata" as well, but I think "progress" fires first.

If preload is set to "auto" or if you've already played some of the video, you **might** have some actual video data. And while you're likely to have data at the current point on the timeline, you may or may not have it at the seek destination. It depends at least on how far ahead (or behind) you're seeking, how fast data is coming in and how much spare room the browser has in the media cache.

If there is no data at the destination time (you can check this in advance if you want with the `.buffered` property, see [TimeRanges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges)), then the next event you see will be either "loadeddata" or "progress", probably followed by "canplay". If there is enough data buffered at the target time of the seek, then the question doesn't really apply because nothing else will be transferred.

However, in any of the above cases, once there is enough data to display the frame at the new point on that timeline and that data has been decoded, the "seeked" event will fire. So if you were to only pick one (no reason you can't use more), this is the one to pick.